# Refactor friendly mocking in dart

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, dart, dart-editor, dart-unittest

So far all the mocking libraries I've seen in dart (unittest/mock, dartmocks) use strings to represent the method calls. e.g.

```dart
foo.when(callsTo('fum')).thenReturn(...);
```

problem is when I want to rename fum then the IDE won't pick up my mocked method calls so I'll have to manually change them.

Anyone aware of any that work with actual method calls (`foo.fum()`)? i.e. similar to mockito etc in Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a tool called [mockito](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mockito) to make this a bit easier. It supports refactoring well.

Comment: Please do not post links to your own work without proper disclaimers; make sure that even properly disclaimed links make up a fairly small proportion of your contributions, not 2/2 posts.

Comment: I do use mockito now. It has made a huge improvement to mocking in dart.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet.

You can star [Symbols create a tooling gap](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=13056)

It's probably a good idea to create a new issue for your requirement as it's different enough.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer. Created [a new issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15793&thanks=15793&ts=1388004322) as you suggested.